# Is it possible to get finer volume control (steps) on a rooted Lenovo M8 tab (HTC Sense UI)?

Tags: settings, volume-control, lenovo, magisk

There's  a popular mod to get finer volume control on a device by adding the property `ro.config.media_vol_steps to /system/etc/prop.default` (android 10) and assigning your prefered steps value, ie '`= 30`' but on my device this results in multiple volume ranges divisible by 15.
Apparently this affects the HTC UI sense as well.

For example if I assign the value 37 to the above property (I do get 37 steps) but when I test by playing something on spotify and increase volume using the buttons I get:

step 0 =  mute

step 15 = max volume

step 16 = mute

step 30 = max volume

step 31 = mute

step 37 = volume 6

Anything below 15 works as expected.
The same happens if you've rooted with Magisk and do it via prop editor or any other editor.

I've been trying to find a solution for this for months with no success hence up the creek with no paddle.

I have coding abilities but for me X86 assembly is easier than than understanding the various tool chains / libraries / compilers required to debug an Android device.

I would like to at least know where in the architecture I should be focusing on.

- Is it vendor or system related?
- A persistent  setting?
- Is the setting pre compiled so would need custom ROM ie a library file change (.so)
  I beleive it must be solvable just hoped I could get at least a hypothetical view of the problem from someone more familiar with the source of Android!

You can get fine volume control from the GUI (swipe down) how can this be mapped to <kbd>Volume up</kbd> / <kbd>Volume down</kbd>?

PS: I should mention I don't have TWRP as it's  not available for this device.

I can now add that installing EdXposed framework along with GravityBox (version Q) also results in the same problem! The modded code above is not found in the prop.default file even tho I have the same problematic functionality, same with magisk modules.

Seems Xposed / gravityBox / magisk are the most powerful tools available to developers for stock software. Im sure there are experts out there that could build a custom software with a simple volume control patch for this device so guess we'll just have to wait. Thanks

Just an update, been a while since this post and the volume control issue is  still unsolved. Im so lucky as Im apparently the only person on the NET who finds this a problem, woohoo! Samsung it is then (will have to mount it portrait)

Comment: Thanks thats already thrown up some interesting reading - vanilla android ! - which sugests the typical 15 vol steps is google's standard and has been since android started god knows why they can't write source code that makes it easy to change, -will post back any useful findings.

Comment: Gravitybox allows up to 50 steps. I just checked as I have it installed

Comment: I  really thought I was on a winner with GravityBox. Installed it ok [version Q] adjusted volume steps to 33, rebooted and same f**!%^g problem. Just a point, did you actually test your 50 steps to see if they work, ie play some music? Regards. Also what device / android version so you have?

Comment: Sorry to hear that. You can ask developer on the XDA thread. In my case I have been using GravityBox volume control for the last five years - Note 2, Honor6, Moto X Play, OnePlus 7 (Android 10)and now on Pixel 4a Android 11 and it always works as advertised //I am very particular on fine volume controls with volume keys // All the best

Comment: EdXposed Whitelist functionality turned off in EdXposed Manager to make GravityBox work properly

Comment: Thanks for your input.